# How to create, name, and run a command in tmux automatically

Tags: bash, tmux

I use tmux for a program I run that sometimes crashes, so I can collect errors from it. I use this method of error collection for a few different programs and would like to know if there's a programmatic way of creating multiple tmux sessions with bash, each having their own name and having a command ran in them.

I have tried doing the following:

```sh
tmux new -ds "myname" "my command"
tmux new -ds "myname2" "my command"
```

however, if the program or command in the tmux session finishes/closes/crashes the tmux session is automatically exited and closed, defeating the purpose of trying to get error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the command not exit. Ex. run the shell after the command, so the shell will wait for you:

```
tmux new -d -s my-session 'sh -c "my command; sh"'
```